# How do I change the margin under chapter?

Tags: spacing

I am using the `scrreprt` class and the margin between `\chapter` and the text is too big. I tried to change it with `\titlespace` but later found out that titlespace does not work for chapters. Is there an easy way to change this margin?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. "Margin" usually refers to the horizontal space on either side of the text. I think you mean "interline spacing" or something like that.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I am new to this. Thank you I will use backticks in the future. Your link solved my problem.